# Setting "start_url" and scope in "manifest.json" for a React PWA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, reverse-proxy, manifest.json

In manifest.json, what exactly is the difference between setting start_url to "." and setting it to "./". Similarly, what exactly is the difference between setting scope to "." and setting it to "./"?

I have a React app deployed behind a reverse proxy server which is accessed by the URL (https://www.example.com/scorer). I am trying to migrate it to a PWA. Pretty easy, except that in manifest.json, I must set

```
"start_url": "./",
"scope": ".",
```

Anything else doesn't seem to work. For example,

```
"start_url": ".",
"scope": ".",
```

doesn't work. I understand that these are relative paths (to the manifest URL), but I just don't get the difference between setting start_url to "." and setting it to "./" (and ,similarly, what the difference between setting scope to "." and setting it to "./").

Answer (score 0):

You can add the to `package.json` an key that called `"homepage"`,
Then the url will start with scope.

If you add:

```
"homepage": "test"
```

Then the url will be : `https://blah.com/test`

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually talking about manifest.json which is used by a PWA installed on, for example, your homescreen. What you suggest must be done if you wish to simply deploy your app through a sub-folder rather than root.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url):

> The start_url member is a string that represents the start URL of the web application

And, according to this [site](https://denmchenry.com/posts/relative-urls/):

[image: Relative path examples]

Therefore "./" would mean that the server should look for the React file inside  the folder. e.g. "C://inetPub/example/scorer".

And "/" would mean that the file should be found inside the root folder. e.g. "C://inetPub/".

But this depends on your server configuration. I've tested it using IIS 5 with default configuration.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful for start_url. But what is the meaning of "scope" being set to "."? You'd think it just means the same as "./", but I'm not sure it does.

Comment: MDN says that: 

"The scope member is a string that defines the navigation scope of this web application's application context. It restricts what web pages can be viewed while the manifest is applied. If the user navigates outside the scope, it reverts to a normal web page inside a browser tab or window.

If the scope is a relative URL, the base URL will be the URL of the manifest."

You could check more about that in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/scope

Comment: Thanks. Yes - I've seen and understood the documentation. The problem is, that in my case, I am seeing behaviour which depends on my scope being set to ".". Setting to "./" breaks things. Not a problem as I can just set to "." and things work. But I would like to understand what the difference could be between the values of "." and "./". I could not find anything in the documentation, hence my question here.

Comment: There is obviously an interaction with the format of the URL which the user places in the browser. For example, if the user wants to access the 'scorer', they might (whether it's correct or not to do so) type in "https://example.com/scorer" or "https://example.com/scorer//". What do the patterns specified by setting scope to "." or "./" actually mean for each of these two URLs?